# iOS geofence tracking 20+ locations with CLLocation distance calculation

Tags: ios, location, cllocationmanager, geofencing, clregion

I have to monitor much more than 20 regions for an iOS app, around 500 to begin with. Therefore I have looked through all the questions related to this issue. I have found that generally people agree that Significant Location Change has to be used in order to recalculate the relative regions for every location change. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15290999/2433921) uses 
a bounding rectangle, which is calculated and later a check is performed in order to see which locations happen to be in the rectangle.

My question is, what if I use `- (CLLocationDistance)getDistanceFrom:(CLLocation *)location` from `CLLocation` in order to calculate the distance from the current location to all 500 other locations. Afterwards sort the distances and find, which are the 20 closest locations and `startMonitoringForRegion`? I assume this is not the most efficient way to do it, but does the efficiency differ from the above mentioned answer? Can I expect performance or battery problems?

Comment: I'm wondering why did they even go with this algorithm, instead of doing what you proposed. It seems so much simpler. Just take the first 20 closest ones.