# geofenced local notifications and region monitoring performance cost and limit

Tags: ios, geofencing

Is there a limit on how many `CLRegions` can one set for getting local notifications in ios? Or is there maybe a performance cost(MKMapView gets slow or takes a long time to load or maybe a significant battery consuption occurs) on setting too many `CLRegions`? For example, would 50 or 150 be too many?

Similar option is to use `region monitoring` and specify `CLCircularregion`s of interest. Is there a limit on how many of them can be set and what performance impact to they cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringForRegion:), you can register up to 20 regions at a time.

> An app can register up to 20 regions at a time. In order to report region changes in a timely manner, the region monitoring service requires network connectivity.

If you need to track more than 20 [here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15290999/4551527) which gives a strategy by loading new regions when a significant location change event occurs.