# Converting distance (nautical miles) into degrees (Lat/Long)

Tags: java, geolocation, google-earth, degrees, openmap

I have entities in a simulation whose initial locations and paths are code using Java in decimal degrees.  I need to scale the sensor radius (it's in nautical miles) and speed (nautical miles/hr) to match decimal degrees.  The purpose is to visualize the sim in OpenMap and Google Earth.

I've seen [How to convert Distance(miles) to degrees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344207/how-to-convert-distancemiles-to-degrees), but the suggestions there don't work.

Any help is appreciated!  I'm thinking it will involve using great circle distance formulas... but can't quite get it.

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253499/simple-calculations-for-working-with-lat-lon-km-distance/1253545#1253545)

Comment: what do you mean by "decimal distance"?

Comment: I don't say "decimal distance", rather "decimal degrees".  And here is what I mean by that: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees

Comment: @TechExchange Using that calculation in OpenMap gives me 30+NM for what is supposed to be 20NM.  Big error when analyzing detections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ed Williams' Aviation Formula https://edwilliams.org/avform.htm is a good, and accessible, place to start. And I often reference http://movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html.

I am guessing that you need a vector of some sort (your question is a bit unclear).

What I use (in C, not Java) to calculate a fix-radial-distance is:

```
void polarToLatLong(double lat, double lon, double dist, double radial,
   double *outlat, double *outlon) {
   if (!dist) { // distance zero, so just return the point
      *outlat = lat;
      *outlon = lon;
   }
   else if (lat > 89.9999) { // North Pole singularity. Dist is in NM.
      *outlat = 90 - dist / 60;
      *outlon = fmod(radial + 180) - 180;
   }
   else { // normal case
      double sinlat, coslon;
      dist /= 3442; // = Earth's radius in nm (not WGS84!)
      sinlat = Sin(lat) * cos(dist) + Cos(lat) * sin(dist) * Cos(radial);
      *outlat = Arcsin(sinlat);
      coslon = (cos(dist) - Sin(lat) * sinlat) / (Cos(lat) * Cos(*outlat));
      *outlon = lon + (Sin(radial) >= 0 : -1 : 1) * Arccos(coslon);
   }
}
```

In the above code `Sin()`, with an upper-case S, is just a wrapper of `sin()` for degrees:

```
#define CLAMP(a,x,b) MIN(MAX(a, x), b) // GTK+ GLib version slightly different
double Sin(double deg)   {return sin(deg * (PI / 180));} // wrappers for degrees
double Cos(double deg)   {return cos(deg * (PI / 180));}
double Arcsin(double x)  {return asin(CLAMP(-1, x, 1)) * (180 / PI);}
double Arccos(double x)  {return acos(CLAMP(-1, x, 1)) * (180 / PI);}
```

Comment: **Edit:** Link to Ed Williams' Aviation Formula is now https://edwilliams.org/avform.htm.