# Using NetTopologySuite, how can I convert meters to degrees?

Tags: distance, latitude-longitude, geography, sqlgeography, nettopologysuite

I have no language preference for an answer; either VB.NET or C# will be fine.

I've seen this problem discussed elsewhere here on SO, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14344207) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14722953), but I've not found solutions that employ the `NetToplogySuite` and `ProjNet` libraries. Further, these other Q&As deal with two known points—I only have one. Therefore, I believe this question to not be a duplicate.

We can easily convert degrees to meters using the sample code found in Microsoft's documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial#srid-ignored-during-client-operations). This works well.

However, in my case I'm querying on a database column. One location is known, but the others aren't. I need to be able to make a call like this:

```vb
oZipCodes = oDb.ZipCodes.Where(Function(Unknown) Unknown.Location.Distance(oKnown.Location) < 22000)
```

EF Core successfully translates this into workable T-SQL. The resulting query, run against the lat/lon coordinates of 33,000 U.S. Zip Codes, is quite fast. The trouble, though, is that the response returned by `Distance()`  is in degrees. The `ProjectTo()` calculation converts degrees to meters as expected, but EF Core fails when it tries to translate this call:

```vb
oZipCodes = oDb.ZipCodes.Where(Function(Unknown) Unknown.Location.ProjectTo(2855).Distance(oKnown.Location.ProjectTo(2855)) < 22000)
```

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet<ZipCode>.Where(z => (Geometry)z.Location.ProjectTo(_2855).Distance(__ProjectTo_0) < 22000)' could not be translated.

I took a brief look at [user-defined function mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping), but that's not a good fit. Any such internalized function would be called 33,000 times for each query, which of course would amount to a significant performance hit.

So it seems that the only solution is to convert the maximum number of meters to degrees before making our `.Location.Distance()` call. In other words, the reverse of what's described in Microsoft's documentation linked above. Best to convert it once for each call, rather than 33,000 times.

How can I use `NetTopologySuite` and `ProjNet` to 'reverse' convert degrees into meters, based on geographical lat/lon coordinates?

(All that said, if there's an easier—and still fast—way to get a list of lat/lon coordinates within a given distance from a given point I'd love to hear about it!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a stored procedure (with miles instead of meters):

```vb
Imports Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations

Namespace Global.Persistence.Migrations.MsSql
  ''' <inheritdoc />
  Partial Public Class _002
    Inherits Migration

    ''' <inheritdoc />
    Protected Overrides Sub Up(migrationBuilder As MigrationBuilder)
      migrationBuilder.Sql("
        CREATE PROCEDURE GetZipCodesWithinRadius
            @Longitude FLOAT,
            @Latitude FLOAT,
            @Radius FLOAT
        AS
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @KnownPoint geography = geography::Point(@Latitude, @Longitude, 4326);
            SELECT *
            FROM ZipCodes
            WHERE @KnownPoint.STDistance(Location) / 1609.34 <= @Radius;
        END")
    End Sub

    ''' <inheritdoc />
    Protected Overrides Sub Down(migrationBuilder As MigrationBuilder)
      migrationBuilder.Sql("DROP PROCEDURE GetZipCodesWithinRadius")
    End Sub
  End Class
End Namespace
```

It's called like this:

```vb
Dim iMaxMiles As Integer
Dim oLongitude As SqlParameter
Dim oLatitude As SqlParameter
Dim oRadius As SqlParameter

iMaxMiles = 100
oLongitude = New SqlParameter("@Longitude", oKnown.Location.Longitude)
oLatitude = New SqlParameter("@Latitude", oKnown.Location.Latitude)
oRadius = New SqlParameter("@Radius", iMaxMiles)

oZipCodes = oDb.ZipCodes.FromSql($"
  GetZipCodesWithinRadius
    @Longitude = {oLongitude},
    @Latitude = {oLatitude},
    @Radius = {oRadius}
  ")

oZipCodes.ForEach(Sub(ZipCode)
                    Console.WriteLine($"{ZipCode.Code}: {ZipCode.City.Name}")
                  End Sub)
```

This neatly bypasses all of the `ProjNet` and `SRID` complexities (which ultimately are unnecessary for this simple task).

It works perfectly.