# Calculating a "box" around latitude and longitude coordinates in Java

Tags: java, android, distance, latitude-longitude

I am trying to get two points, A and B, that are each in 5km distance horizontaly and verticaly around a center point C.
Thus points A and B create a "box" with a side-length of 10km and C is in the exact center of this box.
This is my code:

```
//Distance is 5 kilometers
float distance = 5;    

float latCenter = locationInfo.lastLat;
float lngCenter = locationInfo.lastLong;

// Calculate corner point distance in lat and long
float latDelta = distance/110.54f;
float longDelta = distance/(111.320f(float)Math.cos((double)latCenter));

// Calculate coordinates of the corner points
float latA = lat - latDelta;
float longA = lng - longDelta;
float latB = lat + latDelta;
float longB = lng + longDelta;
```

I know these are approximations, but approximating with a margin of error of ~1km is fine in my case.
The vertical distance is fine (10.06km) but the horizontal distance is only about 6km instead of 10km.

What is wrong with my formula? I guess its some very simple math error, but I just can't find it. I needed a very simple and quick code, so I based my calculations on this StackOverflow answer: [Simple calculations for working with lat/lon + km distance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253499/simple-calculations-for-working-with-lat-lon-km-distance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would bet on *degres vs radians* (from the [javadoc of cos](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#cos%28double%29)):

> `public static double cos(double a)`
>
> Returns the trigonometric cosine of an angle. Special cases:
>   If the argument is NaN or an infinity, then the result is NaN.
>   A result must be within 1 ulp of the correctly rounded result. Results must be semi-monotonic.
>
> Parameters:
>   a - an angle, in radians.
>
> Returns:
>   the cosine of the argument.