# How calculate the Lat/Lon 5km east or north of my current location?

Tags: android, geolocation, android-mapview, geopoints

[image]

I want to calculate the coordinates in Lat/Lon of the points `B` and `C.` And `A` is my current location, for example `Lat: 48.23490` `Lon: 13.177660.`

I retrieve my current location. But now I don't know how to calculate the point B and C.

Refer to my picture please.

This is what I found [>>This<<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253499/simple-calculations-for-working-with-lat-lon-km-distance)

Can anyone help me how to achieve this? But I dont know what I should do with it.

Comment: Have you considered adding 2 more points? D and E ?

Comment: I'm not sure whether [Geographical Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance) can help you or not. I'm not an expert in this field also...

Comment: Do you need an exact result or are approximate values enough?

Comment: I just need the points B and C. It doesn't have to be completly exact.

Comment: I added a link. please take a look at it. But this solution consider not enough explanation for me. I dont know what to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253499/simple-calculations-for-working-with-lat-lon-km-distance) and assuming east is positive, we can do:

```
dy = 5.0 / 110.54;
dx = 5.0 / (111.320*Math.cos(Alat/180*Math.PI));
Blon = Alon + dx;
Blat = Alat + dy;
Clon = Alon - dx;
Clat = Alat - dy;
```

Comment: OK it seems logical. I will test it. Do you know how exact it is? Or whats the variation?

Comment: The accuracy will vary depending on the location, I don't know how large the difference can be in the worst case.

Comment: it says that the `cos()` method is undefined for the type MyActivity. So I can't do it in an Activty?