# calculate boundingbox with Latitude and Longitude in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, google-maps, geometry, coordinates

I need to get the boundingbox around a latitude and longitude with a distance of xx KM.

```
This point o................^
           .                |
           .              100km
           .                |
            <---100km--- lat/lng ---100km--->
                            |               .
                           100km            .
                            |               .
                            V...............o This point
```

So I thought I do a function like this

```
Function latlngToBox(lat As Double, lng As Double, km As Double) As boundingBox

    ' angle per km = 360 / (2 * pi * 6378) = 0.0089833458 (Found this fomula on the web
    Dim angle As Double = km * 0.0089833458
    Dim box As boundingBox = New boundingBox
    box.minLat = lat - angle
    box.minLng = lng - angle
    box.maxLat = lat + angle
    box.maxLng = lng + angle

    Return box

End Function
```

However when I put the points on a map I get this
which is more like a rectangle. 
So I think the formula is wrong.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple calculations for working with lat/lon + km distance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253499/simple-calculations-for-working-with-lat-lon-km-distance)

Comment: Crap you're good and fast. Have Googled half a hour for this. I'm going to check it out.