# How is a km in coordinate?

Tags: maps, coordinates, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

Anyone how much is a kilometer in coordinate for example I can suppose that every five coordinate I have one kilometer? Does it exist one relation in this way? Anyone can suggest me?

Comment: What platform/SDK/environment/language are you using?  It may have these calculations built-in (which involve trigonometry and not a simple multiplication factor).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253499/simple-calculations-for-working-with-lat-lon-km-distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a sphere, the usual coordinates are **angle** measures, latitude and longitude. But if you move along the latitude at the equator by 1 km, the latitude changes only a little, whereas if you move along a latitude close to the north or south pole, the latitude may change arbitrarily much.
The relation that you want to obtain can thus only be valid approximatively, and at a certain region of the sphere.

Answer (score -2):

I needed to do something similar for my currency conversion program, use one variable (kilometers) and set it equal to 5*(coordinate) and go from there. :D

Comment: you are saing that every 5 coordinate is a km?

Comment: yes, then when calculating using the (coordinate) variable, you can convert it into (km) by multiplying by 5