# find nearest users around me using neo4j cypher query

Tags: neo4j

I am using the queries below to create users with lat,lng .

```
MERGE (n { user:'a', id:1,lat:40.736184,lng:-73.992006 })   
MERGE (n { user:'b', id:2,lat:40.748475,lng:-73.993808 })
MERGE (n { user:'c', id:3,lat:40.744638,lng:-73.982135 }) 
MERGE (n { user:'d', id:4,lat:40.708929,lng:-74.005567 }) 
MERGE (n { user:'e', id:5,lat:40.729615,lng:-73.975698 })
```

How to get all users around `40.724152, -74.001276` within `1 km` radius?
I really appreciate any help.

Comment: You may want to look at the neo4j-spatial plugin, that will do it out of the box. Or use a mathematical function (ref google first)

Comment: How can I do it using formula in neo4j ? and How can I install spatial plugin?

Comment: You should use a label for your nodes, and create a constraint on :Label(id)

Comment: I did that Michael.Should I install spatial plugin or is it pre-installed?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the link to the neo4j spatial plugin:

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial

I've not used it before, but most of the instructions are for using it in embedded mode.  But if you're using it in server mode here's a link to the pre-compiled plugins:

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial#using-the-neo4j-spatial-server-plugin

You can do something in Cypher like:

```
ABS(user1.lat - user2.lat) < LAT_NUMBER AND ABS(user1.long - user2.long) < LONG_NUMBER
```

Of course that considers a square.  Also LAT_NUMBER AND LONG_NUMBER would have to be an approximation because a kilometer doesn't have the same ratio to latitude/longitude everywhere on the each (see [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253499/simple-calculations-for-working-with-lat-lon-km-distance).

You could also maybe use good `ol Pythagoras' theorem, though I don't see a way to square numbers in Cypher.  Again, you would then just be coming up with a hypotenuse which is a mix of latitude and longitude.

**(EDIT: See Michael's comment, particularly the link to the docs which has an example of Cypher you could use)**

The spatial plugin should provide the most accurate and predictable results.

Comment: How can I make this sql query into  neo4j query?      **'SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
* cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin(radians(lat)) ) ) AS distance 
FROM markers 
HAVING distance < 25 
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0 , 20;'**

Comment: There is the haversin function in cypher too for this purpose: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-functions-mathematical.html#functions-haversin

Comment: Awesome, TIL!  Thanks, Michael!