# DSE Graph spatial indexes -- search with km?

Tags: solr, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

I'm trying to filter vertices with point properties based on distance, similar to the example at the bottom of the [Using search indexes](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/using/useSearchIndexes.html) section of the docs:

> A query can find all sensors that meet the requirement of being inside the described polygon Distance that is designated as a circle with a center at (-110, 30) and a radius of 20 *units* with the method Geo.inside().

The "units" used for the radius are actually degrees. What I would like is to find the points within a certain radius in kilometers.

This is apparently supported by Solr, (see `distanceUnits`[here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spatial+Search#SpatialSearch-Schemaconfiguration)) and is even the default in the upstream distribution. I tried to change `schema.xml` to set `distanceUnits=kilometers` in the configuration for RPT, but then the solr core threw the following exception on reload:

`org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Must specify units="degrees" on field types with class SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DSE5 we are running solr 4.10.3.2.1133 [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/RNdse.html#RNdse__50comp) the only valid type for Units in this version is degrees as we can see from the [code](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/releases/lucene-solr/4.10.3/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/schema/AbstractSpatialFieldType.java#L111-L114)
.  Units was the predecessor to distanceUnits.  In the meantime you may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253499/simple-calculations-for-working-with-lat-lon-km-distance) helpful.