# get left, right, top and button coordinates

Tags: javascript, node.js

with one coordinate (latitude, longitude) and some distance, how can i get left and right longitude and and top and button latitude?
example:

i only want to get left and right longitude, up and down latitude using center point and X distance (X in km) (coordinates of U, L, R and D coordinates) in any part of hearth

i'm using nodejs

[like image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66DwW.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about latitude and longitude rather than programming per se.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple calculations for working with lat/lon + km distance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253499/simple-calculations-for-working-with-lat-lon-km-distance)