# how to add an offset value to a geographical coordinate

Tags: gis

I have a geographical coordinate points such as latitude : 12.920257 longitude : 77.620677. How can i add 4 meters to the east and west of the point and also how can i add 20 meters to the north and the south of the point?

Comment: this question is pretty vague, what did you try to solve the problem? is it even computer science related? what technologie are you using?

Comment: I need to use real time gps for my application. Application is basically related with V2X technology.

Answer (score 1):

here are some approximative conversions

- Latitude: 1 deg = 110.574 km
- Longitude: 1 deg = 111.320*cos(latitude)
  km

to answer your question :

- 4 meters east/west = 0.00003617486 deg latitude
- 4 meters north/south = 0.00003593244 * cos(latitude) deg longitude

remember to convert the latitude using this `radians = degrees * PI / 180` before using the `cos`

**note :** the numbers probably need more complicated equations as earth is not perfectly round

**source :** [Simple calculations for working with lat/lon + km distance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253499/simple-calculations-for-working-with-lat-lon-km-distance)

Comment: what is the formula that can be used to find this solution?