# getting the size of the map Sumo

Tags: openstreetmap, omnet++, sumo

I exported a part of my city using OpenstreetMap, so I have a .osm file that contains at the beginning of the file:

```
<bounds minlat="34.8743000" minlon="-1.3494000" maxlat="34.9035000" maxlon="-1.2926000"/>
```

The file .node.xml contains :

```
<location netOffset="-650593.12,-3860745.37" convBoundary="0.00,0.00,4960.80,3134.19" origBoundary="-1.384393,34.847744,-1.297697,34.916012" projParameter="+proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"/>
```

I want to know the size of my map in Km. How do I do it?

Comment: Hi.  Check here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253499/simple-calculations-for-working-with-lat-lon-and-km-distance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boundary coordinates are in meters so it is 4960.80m x 3134.19m

Comment: It is the right response, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The approximate conversions are:

Latitude: 1 deg = 110.574 km

Longitude: 1 deg = 111.320*cos(latitude) km.

For a details check out the comment under the question