# Bearing using two sets of coordinates (Latitude and Longitude) in C

Tags: c, coordinates, latitude-longitude, bearing

I have began working on an autonomous rc helicopter in c. I need help finding a way to calculate the bearing acuratley. I am using two sets of coordinates (latitude and longitude), one is the current location and the other is the destination point. I have converted the latitude and longitude into decimal format so....

```
40°58'19.86"N = 40.972183
74°14'52.74"W = 74.247983
```

Can anyone show me code in c to find the bearing or a formula i can use?

i have looked at: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html and when i transfer it to c, the results make no sense.

This is what i have tried:

```
 double x = Sin(Longitude2 - Longitude1) * Cos(Latitude2);
 double y = Cos(Latitude1) * Sin(Latitude2) - Sin(Latitude1) * Cos(Latitude2) * Cos(Longitude2 - Longitude1);
 double heading = (Atan2(x, y) % 2 * 3.14159265) (180/3.14159265);
```

Comment: Show us the C code you've attempted.

Comment: i just added the code i have tried

Comment: double heading = (fmod(atan2(x, y), 2) * 3.14159265) * (180/3.14159265);  ---> would that be the correct implementation?

Answer (score 2):

Have you converted your coordinates from degrees to radians before calculations ?

`angleRad = 3.14159265 * angleDeg / 180;`
And

`bearing = Atan2(y, x);`
in that website.
The bearing should be converted from rad to deg in turn:

`bearing = 180 * bearing / 3.14159265;`
and in case of negative value eventually:

`bearing = bearing + 360;`

I don't know how to write this using the convention above (with "%").

Latitude1 and Longitude1 are coordinates of the observer
Latitude2 and Longitude2 are coordinates of destination point.

Formulas from that website work well.

Answer (score 1):

For the very small area you are considering you can assume the world is flat.
If you also only need this to work locally you can pre-calculate the value of a deg lat/lon on the ground in metres (or ft)

Then simply convert the delta lat/lon into distance and do the normal trig.

To convert distance to lat/lon you can either use google earth to measure it or 
[How to convert latitude or longitude to meters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639695/how-to-convert-latitude-or-longitude-to-meters)