# How can i find the Bounding Longitude / Latitude of an Area around a Single GeoPoint?

Tags: geolocation, nosql

I'd like to Select GeoPoints (Longitude / Latitude) roughly within a Radius or Rectangular Area (say 5km).

I'm doing this in Map/Reduce (Not SQL)

I'm finding Map/Reduce does NOT like to reduce on calculated fields.
As such - I'm wondering if I can simply Select a Range of Longitudes & Latitudes?

Example:

Target Area is Between Longitude 4.1234 & 4.77889 (SELECT Rows WHERE Long >= 4.1234 && <=4.77889)
Target Area is Between Latitude 9.1234 & 9.77889 (SELECT Rows WHERE Lat >= 9.1234 && <=9.77889)

**How can i find the (Aprox) Bounding Longitude / Latitude of an Area around a Single GeoPoint?**

Comment: Is it possible you could elaborate more on how you did this? I am doing something similar, where I want to list the nearest 10 latitude/longitudes using Map/Reduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to convert lat long in to distance (meter / km) then you can apply query

use following link

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

[How to convert latitude or longitude to meters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639695/how-to-convert-latitude-or-longitude-to-meters)