# Convert Latitude and Longitude into kms

Tags: php, laravel-4, latitude-longitude

I am building application where i am getting the user's `latitude` and `longitude` using the below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script> var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    } }

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;   } </script>

</body> </html>
```

Now i want to convert it to kilometre so that i can compare with other latitude and longitude and calculate the difference between them in kilometre.

Comment: tried anything so far ?

Comment: I am getting the lat and lng.. I was wondering if my approach is correct that if i convert it to km and then compare with other so i can get difference ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This Script is usefull for you, but its in php

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

      $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
      $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
       $dist = acos($dist);
       $dist = rad2deg($dist);
      $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
      $unit = strtoupper($unit);

 if ($unit == "K") {
   return ($miles * 1.609344);
     } else if ($unit == "N") {
     return ($miles * 0.8684);
      } else {
      return $miles;
     }
  }
```

> Function to use

```
  echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "M") . " Miles<br>";
  echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "K") . " Kilometers<br>";
  echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "N") . " Nautical Miles<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that a latitude and longitude is a specific point, you cannot convert this directly to kilometers, which is a distance i.e. the length separating **two** points.

But you can get the distance between two coordinates (lat+long) with a math formula.
I am not really good at math, but you could find such formula with a simple search on Google: 
[here is the first result](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

You may also find something useful on this topic:
[How to convert latitude or longitude to meters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639695/how-to-convert-latitude-or-longitude-to-meters)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula); there's a PHP implementation [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula#PHP).