# Filtering Spatial Data in Apache Spark

Tags: algorithm, apache-spark, gps, apache-spark-sql, geospatial

I am currently solving a problem involving GPS data from buses. The issue I am facing is to reduce computation in my process.

There are about 2 billion GPS-coordinate points (Lat-Long degrees) in one table and about 12,000 bus-stops with their Lat-Long in another table. It is expected that only 5-10% of the 2-billion points are at bus-stops.

**Problem**: I need to tag and extract only those points (out of the 2-billion) that are at bus-stops (the 12,000 points). Since this is GPS data, I cannot do exact matching of the coordinates, but rather do a tolerance based geofencing.

**Issue**: The process of tagging bus-stops is taking extremely long time with the current naive approach. Currently, we are picking each of the 12,000 bus-stop points, and querying the 2-billion points with a tolerance of 100m (by converting degree-differences into distance).

**Question**: Is there an algorithmically efficient process to achieve this tagging of points?

Comment: Using k-d tree would be place to start.

Comment: I worked on a similar usecase. We used the properties of `GeoHashes` to define cells and define the process per cell instead. This is still a broad question. Maybe you could show the code of your current approach to drive the discussion?

Comment: @LostInOverflow - sure, going through it.

Comment: @maasg - that seems to be a rather good idea - I shall give it a shot! Currently, the code is just a set of hive queries. But the final work needs to be done in Spark - hence the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use something like [SpatialSpark](https://github.com/sabman/SpatialSpark). It only works with Spark 1.6.1 but you can use [BroadcastSpatialJoin](https://github.com/sabman/SpatialSpark/blob/master/src/test/scala/spatialspark/join/BroadcastSpatialJoinSpec.scala) to create an `RTree` which is extremely efficient.

Here's an example of me using SpatialSpark with PySpark to check if different polygons are within each other or are intersecting:

```
from ast import literal_eval as make_tuple
print "Java Spark context version:", sc._jsc.version()
spatialspark = sc._jvm.spatialspark

rectangleA = Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 10), (10, 10), (10, 0)])
rectangleB = Polygon([(-4, -4), (-4, 4), (4, 4), (4, -4)])
rectangleC = Polygon([(7, 7), (7, 8), (8, 8), (8, 7)])
pointD = Point((-1, -1))

def geomABWithId():
  return sc.parallelize([
    (0L, rectangleA.wkt),
    (1L, rectangleB.wkt)
  ])

def geomCWithId():
  return sc.parallelize([
    (0L, rectangleC.wkt)
  ])

def geomABCWithId():
  return sc.parallelize([
  (0L, rectangleA.wkt),
  (1L, rectangleB.wkt),
  (2L, rectangleC.wkt)])

def geomDWithId():
  return sc.parallelize([
    (0L, pointD.wkt)
  ])

dfAB                 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(geomABWithId(), ['id', 'wkt'])
dfABC                = sqlContext.createDataFrame(geomABCWithId(), ['id', 'wkt'])
dfC                  = sqlContext.createDataFrame(geomCWithId(), ['id', 'wkt'])
dfD                  = sqlContext.createDataFrame(geomDWithId(), ['id', 'wkt'])

# Supported Operators: Within, WithinD, Contains, Intersects, Overlaps, NearestD
SpatialOperator      = spatialspark.operator.SpatialOperator 
BroadcastSpatialJoin = spatialspark.join.BroadcastSpatialJoin

joinRDD = BroadcastSpatialJoin.apply(sc._jsc, dfABC._jdf, dfAB._jdf, SpatialOperator.Within(), 0.0)

joinRDD.count()

results = joinRDD.collect()
map(lambda result: make_tuple(result.toString()), results)

# [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0)] read as:
# ID 0 is within 0
# ID 1 is within 1
# ID 2 is within 0
```

Note the line

```
joinRDD = BroadcastSpatialJoin.apply(sc._jsc, dfABC._jdf, dfAB._jdf, SpatialOperator.Within(), 0.0)
```

the last argument is a buffer value, in your case it would be the tolerance you want to use. It will probably be a very small number if you are using lat/lon since it's a radial system and depending on the meters you want for your tolerance you will need to [calculate based on lat/lon for your area of interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639695/how-to-convert-latitude-or-longitude-to-meters).