# how to convert decimal degree to metric unit in simulating the moving of an object in c#

Tags: c#, coordinate-systems, metric, unit-conversion, geographic-distance

i have a simulating of moving object in c#. i have some coordinates and speed(moving force) vector value in every coordinate. all of the coordination are decimal degree like below:

```
lon:57.513958 lat:30.369513
```

in each point there is two force value in horizontal and vertical directions that move the object spawned in that place. these forces unit is metric (m/s) but the coordinate is decimal degree. now problem is: how can i find exact location of object when the moving vector unit is metric and locations are decimal? how can i convert them to eachother

Comment: Please see [How to convert latitude or longitude to meters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639695/how-to-convert-latitude-or-longitude-to-meters)