# Convert Latitude longitude to meters / feet in ( haversine in python )

Tags: python, gps, maps, haversine

I already find this answer [How to convert latitude or longitude to meters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639695/how-to-convert-latitude-or-longitude-to-meters) and about haversine formula but it's written in javascript.

I want to know how can I give two coordinates like

```
48.829911, 2.373527
48.825843, 2.374273
```

and he will return for example there are 450 meters between them ? 
Do you have some function or library that I can use ? 
Thnks

Comment: According to my calculations, using `geographiclib`, the WGS84 distance between those two locations is 455.69153 metres.

Comment: I don't need the distance , it was an example, and I already had the distance with google maps feature. But I want to calculate it that with python not C++.

Comment: My code in the linked answer uses the WGS84 ellipsoid, rather than  simple spherical trigonometry using haversine, so it's much more accurate. WGS84 is what the GPS system uses.

Comment: If you don't need the distance then why did you say that you want to calculate distance? But anyway, check out `geographiclib`, it is _very_ good.

Comment: Read it again, I said " Do you have some function or library that I can use " . You give me a library that I can use with c++ . Are you talking about this page https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/python/ ?

Comment: Requests for libraries are off-topic on Stack Overflow. But yes, I recommend geographiclib, which is available in various languages. ;) And the question I linked shows how to use geographiclib from Python to compute distances between locations. Those docs in your last comment show you how to do a few other tasks as well. The full geographiclib can do even more, but sadly not all of its power is directly accessible from the Python package.