# How to calculate coordinates of N equidistant points along a straight line between 2 coordinates on a map?

Tags: maps, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I have two points on a map -

```
val point1 : LatLng(13.3016139,77.4219107)
val point2 : LatLng(14.1788932,77.7613413)
```

I want to calculate and find 100 equidistant points along a straight line between these two coordinates. How do I do that?

ps. I'm sure this has been asked before, I just can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it -

```
fun findEquidistantPoints(latLng1: LatLng, latLng2: LatLng, pointCount: Int): ArrayList<LatLng> {

    if (pointCount < 0)
        throw IllegalArgumentException("PointCount cannot be less than 0")

    val points = ArrayList<LatLng>()

    val displacement = latLng1.displacementFromInMeters(latLng2)
    val distanceBetweenPoints = displacement / (pointCount + 1)

    for (i in 1..pointCount) {
        val t = (distanceBetweenPoints * i) / displacement

        points.add(LatLng(
                (1 - t) * latLng1.latitude + t * latLng2.latitude,
                (1 - t) * latLng1.longitude + t * latLng2.longitude
        ))
    }

    return points
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Equidistant, and more importantly, straight by which projection?

usually, to find a distance in cartesian space one would use something like the 
[Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to find a value, as previously answered in [stack answer: How to convert latitude or longitude to meters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639695/how-to-convert-latitude-or-longitude-to-meters#11172685)

As for the equidistant part, once you have the distance decided as per your taste of the shape and radius of Earth at given points, a simple division will do. .

```
python 3.7
>>> dist = 5427 #just some number
>>> nbr_o_points = 101 
>>> points = [(dist/nbr_o_points)*(i+1) for i in range(nbr_o_points)]
>>> [f'{p:.2f}' for p in points]
['53.73', '107.47', '161.20',..., '5319.53', '5373.27', '5427.00']
```

Now to transfer these distances from point a to b back onto the desired projection... This is not part of your question...  [Stack - how-to-determine-vector-between-two-lat-lon-points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79633/how-to-determine-vector-between-two-lat-lon-points) might help.

take the vector and multiply by the dists in points in order to get your coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for that answer, but this is not the code I'm looking for. This only outputs a list of equidistant distance values divided by number of point. The 2nd link you sent will help though. Using that and the Haversine formula we can find those coordinates.