# Method for calculate distance between two coordinates?

Tags: angular, dictionary, leaflet

I'm using Angular 10 and ngx-leaflet. I have two points with lat and lng, how can I calculate distance (in meter) between these points? I need display it in template, is it some method to calculate it? Thanks.

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#latlng-distanceto

Comment: U can have a look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639695/how-to-convert-latitude-or-longitude-to-meters).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a method to calculate the distance, you can simply use the coordinates of the two points you want to use and do a little bit of math.
The formula to calculate the distance between two points in a 2D space is rather simple :
[Formula 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwXE0.jpg)

But in a 3D space it's a bit more complicated, but still easy to use :
[Formula 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0bXR.png)