# Android Google Maps: Cut hole in polygon using polyline

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Is it possible to cut holes (or create a sort of mask image) using `Polyline`?

Similar to simply drawing `Polylines` over the top of a `Polygon` except the lines serve as masks/holes that 'erase' the polygon area. On the left is what I can currently achieve with a `Polygon` object that spans the entire map and a few `Polyline` objects over the top. On the right is the goal:

[image]

Below is the code I currently use to create the simple lines over the map:

```
override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?) {
    locationResult ?: return
    locationResult.lastLocation.let {
        if (it.accuracy > 0.5) {
            lastLocation = it
            drawTrail(LatLng(it.latitude, it.longitude))
        }
    }
}

private fun drawTrail(newLocation: LatLng) {
    oldLine?.remove()
    currentTrail.add(newLocation)
    oldLine = map.addPolyline(currentTrail)
}
```

I understand that you are able to create holes in `Polygon` objects using a list of `LatLng` objects but this requires you to provide 5 coordinates to create a single hole shape. I've also had issues with these hole objects where the `Polygon` fill disappears if the holes overlap each other or aren't valid in some way. Therefore I'm looking for an alternate approach to creating complex holes.

Comment: Please take a look at answer update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway you can implement custom view, which extends `MapView` (or `MapFragment`) class for full control of drawing on view canvas in `dispatchDraw()`:

```
...
@Override
public void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();
    drawMaskAndPolygonOverTheMap(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
...
```

For converting polygon geographic `LatLng` coordinates into screen coordinates you can use `toScreenLocation()` method of [`Projection`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/maps/Projection) class:

```
Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
Point pointScreenCoords = projection.toScreenLocation(pointLatLngCoordinates);
```

**UPDATE:***

For example, with custom `MapView` like this:

```
public class PathMapView extends MapView implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final float LINE_WIDTH_IN_METERS = 45;
    private OnMapReadyCallback mMapReadyCallback;
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private Paint mPaintPath;
    private Paint mPaintBackground;
    private Paint mPaintBitmap;
    private ArrayList<LatLng> mPathPoints;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mBitmapCanvas;

    public PathMapView(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public PathMapView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public PathMapView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    public PathMapView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable GoogleMapOptions options) {
        super(context, options);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.save();
        drawPolylineOverTheMap(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    private void drawPolylineOverTheMap(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mGoogleMap == null || mPathPoints == null || mPathPoints.size() < 2) {
            return;
        }

        if (mBitmap == null) {
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mBitmapCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        }

        mBitmapCanvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), mPaintBackground);

        double metersPerPixel = (Math.cos(mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target.latitude * Math.PI / 180) * 2 * Math.PI * 6378137) / (256 * Math.pow(2, mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom));
        float lineWidth = (float) (LINE_WIDTH_IN_METERS / metersPerPixel);
        mPaintPath.setStrokeWidth(lineWidth);

        Projection projection = mGoogleMap.getProjection();
        for (int i = 1; i < mPathPoints.size(); i++) {
            final Point point1 = projection.toScreenLocation(mPathPoints.get(i-1));
            final Point point2 = projection.toScreenLocation(mPathPoints.get(i));
            mBitmapCanvas.drawLine(point1.x, point1.y, point2.x, point2.y, mPaintPath);
        }

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, null, new Rect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()), mPaintBitmap);
    }

    private void init() {
        setWillNotDraw(false);

        mPaintPath = new Paint();
        mPaintPath.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        mPaintPath.setStrokeWidth(25);
        mPaintPath.setAlpha(255);
        mPaintPath.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

        mPaintBackground = new Paint();
        mPaintBackground.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mPaintBackground.setAlpha(155);
        mPaintBackground.setStrokeWidth(15);

        mPaintBitmap = new Paint();
        mPaintBitmap.setAlpha(50);
    }

    @Override
    public void getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback callback) {
        mMapReadyCallback = callback;
        super.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraMove() {
                invalidate();
            }
        });
        if (mMapReadyCallback != null) {
            mMapReadyCallback.onMapReady(googleMap);
        }
    }

    public void setPathPoints(final ArrayList<LatLng> pathPoints) {
        mPathPoints = pathPoints;
    }
}
```

and its usage this way:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY = "MapViewBundleKey";
    static final LatLng V_ICE_SCREAMS = new LatLng(52.99728959196756, -1.1899122739632702);

    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private PathMapView mMapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Bundle mapViewBundle = null;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
        }

        mMapView = (PathMapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mMapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle);
        mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                mGoogleMap = googleMap;

                final ArrayList<LatLng> pathPoints = new ArrayList<>();
                pathPoints.add(new LatLng(52.99728191304702, -1.1898995151709677));
                pathPoints.add(new LatLng(52.99729343143402, -1.1915964365223883));
                pathPoints.add(new LatLng(52.997462367423275, -1.1892870924275978));
                pathPoints.add(new LatLng(52.99732798657649, -1.1888979488094147));
                pathPoints.add(new LatLng(52.99848364819607, -1.1887576019291894));
                pathPoints.add(new LatLng(52.99842989717891, -1.1903460734198053));
                pathPoints.add(new LatLng(52.99632203666474, -1.1900781384562662));
                pathPoints.add(new LatLng(52.99728959196756, -1.1898484799275026));

                mMapView.setPathPoints(pathPoints);

                mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(V_ICE_SCREAMS,15));
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        Bundle mapViewBundle = outState.getBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
        if (mapViewBundle == null) {
            mapViewBundle = new Bundle();
            outState.putBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY, mapViewBundle);
        }

        mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(mapViewBundle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mMapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mMapView.onStop();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mMapView.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mMapView.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }

}
```

you should get as result something like this:

[image: Transparent path example]

Path width depends on zoom level (it set in meters, not in pixals) and you can control it by with `LINE_WIDTH_IN_METERS` constant (`45` meters set now). Intensity of path you can control by values in `.setAlpha();` calls.

NB! It's just example, not perfect solution.

Comment: Fantastic solution. Now I just need to be able to handle the zooming and moving around the map! But this very much solves the issue of cutting a hole to reveal the map behind. `projection.toScreenLocation()` is magic. Thankyou for taking the time to answer this!

Comment: Also, `Math.cos(mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target.latitude * Math.PI / 180) * 2 * Math.PI * 6378137) / (256 * Math.pow(2, mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom)` is a crazy bit of math, may I ask where you found it and what `6378137` represents?

Comment: @KesWalker It is [Earth radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius) in meters (approximately). This "crazy math" (not exactly) needed because one degree of latitude near equator and one degree of latitude near poles are not equal in meters (due Earth shape) - near poles one degree converts to less meters (like on [this image](https://www.opendem.info/images/arc2meters.png)).

Comment: @KesWalker "Now I just need to be able to handle the zooming and moving around the map!" - the solution should work for that cases.

Comment: @KesWalker also about [math](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11172685/6950238).