# Show google maps polyline only on specific part of device screen

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Good day to you all, I am creating a ride app and I was asking for some assistance in the following problem I am facing.

So, On the image below the grey background represents a google map fragment and above it sits two views(black) I wanted to know if it were possible to only show a polyline and markers between the black views only in the red area and have the rest of the map showing in the background as well.

If it helps I have managed to get the LatLng's of the corners of the red box using:

```
googleMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation();
```

Thank you in advance!

[image: example image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Several ways. For example, the red area of your figure can be `View` (e.g. custom view) with transparent background and you can draw your polylines on it (you need to take into account position of transparent "red" view on map view for correction of `fromScreenLocation()/toScreenLocation()` methods results). Also, probably, you can use two `MapView`s one over another and synchronize its scrolling and zooming, but IMHO best way is to to implement [custom view component](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components) based on `MapVew` (or `MapFragment`) an override `onDraw()` for `MapVew`-based (or `dispatchDraw()` for `MapFragment`-based) method like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50591194/6950238) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68291479/6950238) answers:

```
..
@Override
public void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();
    drawPolylinesInRegion(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
...
```

In `drawPolylinesInRegion(canvas);` method you should draw your polylines and markers "manually" converting coordinates of them via method opposite you mentioned: [`toScreenLocation()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/maps/Projection#toScreenLocation(com.google.android.libraries.maps.model.LatLng)) and taking into account size of "gray regions" of you example figure.