# Customizing Compass to work between two geopoints

Tags: android, compass-geolocation

I have one requirement in which i want to show the arrow towards one location from current location.Also it should move as per the device rotation and should point to same location after location also.Is it possible ? How?

I have refferd this link [Rotating an ImageView like a compass (with the "north pole" set elsewhere)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978618/rotating-an-imageview-like-a-compass-with-the-north-pole-set-elsewhere) but its not working for me.

Comment: Please describe 'its not working for me'...

Comment: My image not pointing towards the desired location as per the device rotation properly.

Comment: What goes wrong? Does it trigger the onSensorChanged event? If so, does the method rotateImageView receives the right rotate parameter?

Comment: Yes its triggering onSensorChanged and I am getting direction calculation between 190.4128 to 198.590 for testing I have set one point as a destination.

Comment: Well, this is info you should have included in the first post when asking the question. This way we don't have to ask these things and you probably get an answer much faster...