# Calculate geolocation heading in android

Tags: android, geolocation, heading

I am making an app in which I have to calculate heading in location but I did not found any necessary data in which I could calculate heading of location. I used the following link too but all in vain. [Calculate compass bearing / heading to location in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308262/calculate-compass-bearing-heading-to-location-in-android)

Can anyone help me in this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Frankenstein , Heading means compass bearing / heading to location and please refer the link mentioned by me.

Comment: @Aditya1510 did u find any solution for this,I am also trying to do same thing but I am facing problem with device heading.If u find a solution please post it.Thanks...