# How to display the compass like google latitude?

Tags: android, android-mapview, compass-geolocation, google-latitude

I'm currently working on a mapview, and I want to display the user's position like the google's Latitude (compass direction);
I saw several topic on that, but none of them give me the adequate solution for my query.
Do you have a tutorial or examples to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`MyLocationOverlay`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html). Example code:

```
public MyMapActivity extends MapActivity {
  private MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay;
  private MapView mapView;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.my_map_layout);

    mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map_view);

    myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    myLocationOverlay.enableCompass();
    myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    myLocationOverlay.disableCompass();
    myLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation();
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i already try this solution but, the position is a dot, and I want an arrow showing the direction of the compass, like the google's latitude

Comment: :the showing position is a dot, but i want the arrow like the google's latitude app : you see what i mean ?
like this : http://img.clubic.com/04058312-photo-google-maps-5-2-pour-android-ping.jpg

Comment: There is nothing out of the box that looks like that. Best chance is to override MyLocationOverlay to draw the icon you like.

Comment: I tried that to, but the icon does not rotate properly. I use matrix.postRotate (bearing);
before drawing.
My icon is the compass direction every 5-10 seconds

Answer (score 0):

May be this answer solves your problem with rotating the icon: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8712727/1127492

You may also consider preparing 8 (or 16) (small!) icons for the 8 (or 16) main directions and select the icon depending on bearing/8 (resp. /16).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody is facing out this problem anymore.
First of all, this needs both `LocationListener` and `SensorEventListener`. [Here you can find more details of how to use it in this scope.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308262/calculate-compass-bearing-heading-to-location-in-android)
Anyway, `Android Google Maps V2 Api` partially solves this problem, displaying an arrow indicating your orientation but only when the device is moving otherway a dot will be displayed.