# Rotating Image on A canvas in android

Tags: android, rotation, android-canvas, angle

I want to Rotate Image according to a specific angle in android ,some thing like a compass...

I have this code...it works on drawPath()
but i want to replace the path and the Drawing thing with image..
I tried to create a bitmap image ,DrawBitmapImage , but the image does not Rotate like the path..Any Help PLease?

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    double angle = calculateAngle(currentLongitude, currentLatitude, targetLongitude, targetLatitude);

    //Correction;
    angle-=90;

    //Correction for azimuth
    angle-=azimuth;

    if((getContext() instanceof Activity) && ((Activity)getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation()==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)angle-=90;

    while(angle<0)angle=angle+360;

    Rect rect = canvas.getClipBounds();

    int height = rect.bottom-rect.top;
    int width = rect.right-rect.left;
    int left = rect.left;
    int top = rect.top;

    if(height>width){
        top+=(height-width)/2;
        height=width;
    }
    if(width>height){
        left+=(width-height)/2;
        width=height;
    }

    float centerwidth = width/2f;
    float centerheight = height/2f;

    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(color);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    p.setAntiAlias(true);

    float startX = left+(float)(centerwidth+Math.cos(deg2rad(angle))*width/3.0);
    float startY = top+(float)(centerheight+Math.sin(deg2rad(angle))*height/3.0);

    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(
            startX,
            startY);
    path.lineTo(
            left+(float)(centerwidth+Math.cos(deg2rad(angle+140))*width/4.0),
            top+(float)(centerheight+Math.sin(deg2rad(angle+140))*height/4.0));
    path.lineTo(
            left+(float)centerwidth,
            top+(float)centerheight
            );
    path.lineTo(
            left+(float)(centerwidth+Math.cos(deg2rad(angle+220))*width/4.0), 
            top+(float)(centerheight+Math.sin(deg2rad(angle+220))*height/4.0)
            );

    path.lineTo(
            startX,
            startY
            );




    canvas.drawPath(path, p);
}
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can either rotate your bitmap when you draw it by using a matrix:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate(angle, imageCenterX, imageCenterY);
yourCanvas.drawBitmap(yourBitmap, matrix, null);
```

You can also do it by rotating the canvas before drawing:

```
yourCanvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG); //Saving the canvas and later restoring it so only this image will be rotated.
yourCanvas.rotate(-angle);
yourCanvas.drawBitmap(yourBitmap, left, top, null);
yourCanvas.restore();
```

Pick the one that suits you the best.

Comment: @Jave, I think the first approach can be used, in particular, where you want to rotate an image or bitmap around x-axis and/or y-axis as `Canvas` doesn't have rotation methods other than the one which does it in XY-plane. I think one can get a `Camera` object and make necessary 3D transformations and finally use `getMatrix` passing `Matrix` instance to get the corresponding `Matrix` representation. Lastly, pass this `Matrix` to `drawBitmap` method. Specifically, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32554925/android-animate-rotation-of-map-marker-around-x-and-y-axis): Any thoughts. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You have to rotate the canvas first and then draw whatever you want. Then the object drawn will be appeared as rotated on screen.

```
canvas.rotate(45); // degrees to rotate
```

try this its good way.

Check this tutorial you will get information about how to draw bitmap and how to rotate canvas

[Check complete tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-use-canvas-your-android-apps-part-2)

Comment: Rotate the canvas according to the angle?
Then what?
Just creating Bitmap and draw it

Comment: it seem to be you didn't read information available at Android Developers website. In Canvas class many functions are available to draw Bitmap. You have to call any drwaBitmap() after canvas.rotate() according to your requirement.

Comment: @Reham did you checked the link ? Did you got solution to your problem ? if my answer/suggestion solves your problem please mark it as answer. bye :-)

Comment: I checked your answer and thank you very much..i think its the right solution...but until now i'm stuck in the same problem...the image is rotating around the screen...i don't have much experience in canvas and the drawing thing..:(

Comment: this code solved my problem a little...:)

  Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
             b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.arrow) ;
mtx.reset();
  
   mtx.setTranslate(rect.exactCenterX(),rect.exactCenterY());
  
    mtx.postRotate((float)angle,rect.exactCenterX(),rect.exactCenterY());
  
canvas.drawBitmap(b, mtx,p);

Answer (score 2):

This is the only one that worked for me with no problem.

```
    private Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int rotationAngleDegree){

        int w = bitmap.getWidth();
        int h = bitmap.getHeight();

        int

 newW=w, newH=h;
    if (rotationAngleDegree==90 || rotationAngleDegree==270){
        newW = h;
        newH = w;
    }
    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(newW,newH, bitmap.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(rotatedBitmap);

    Rect rect = new Rect(0,0,newW, newH);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    float px = rect.exactCenterX();
    float py = rect.exactCenterY();
    matrix.postTranslate(-bitmap.getWidth()/2, -bitmap.getHeight()/2);
    matrix.postRotate(rotationAngleDegree);
    matrix.postTranslate(px, py);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, new Paint( Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.DITHER_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG ));
    matrix.reset();

    return rotatedBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Sakthi 's code, but add **scaling** :)

```
        Rect rect = new Rect(0,0,canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postTranslate(-bitmap.getWidth()/2, -bitmap.getHeight()/2);
        matrix.postScale(
                ((float)rect.width()) / bitmap.getWidth(),
                ((float)rect.height()) / bitmap.getHeight());
        matrix.postRotate(180);
        matrix.postTranslate(rect.exactCenterX(), rect.exactCenterY());
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);
```

Comment: Thanks, this all didn't work for me if i wanted to rotate a bitmap at position

Answer (score 1):

@Reham: Look at this example code below,

```
public class bitmaptest extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

    // load the origial BitMap (500 x 500 px)
    Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
           R.drawable.android);

    int width = bitmapOrg.width();
    int height = bitmapOrg.height();
    int newWidth = 200;
    int newHeight = 200;

    // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

    // createa matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    // rotate the Bitmap
    matrix.postRotate(45);

    // recreate the new Bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0,
                      width, height, matrix, true);

    // make a Drawable from Bitmap to allow to set the BitMap
    // to the ImageView, ImageButton or what ever
    BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

    // set the Drawable on the ImageView
    imageView.setImageDrawable(bmd);

    // center the Image
    imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);

    // add ImageView to the Layout
    linLayout.addView(imageView,
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                  LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
            )
    );

    // set LinearLayout as ContentView
    setContentView(linLayout);
}
}
```

you have to use the matrix to rotate image look the lines

```
matrix.postRotate(45); -
```

this will rotate the image to 45 degrees

Hope this help you ...thx

Comment: I think you've typoed `bitmapOrg.width()` for `bitmapOrg.getWidth()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code. it worked for me

float rotation = 30.0f;

```
     Bitmap bitmap = your bitmap
     Rect rect = new Rect(100,100,bitmap.width, bitmap.height);
     Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
     float px = rect.exactCenterX();
     float py = rect.exactCenterY();
     matrix.postTranslate(-bitmap.getWidth()/2, -bitmap.getHeight()/2);
     matrix.postRotate(rotation);
     matrix.postTranslate(px, py);
     canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);
     matrix.reset();
     invalidate();
```

Comment: This is nice. Just made small modification to make it start from 0,0

Comment: Ya sure. Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height);