# How to rotate a drawable on canvas in android

Tags: java, android, rotation, android-canvas, android-drawable

Lets say i place mutile drawables on a canvas at different places.
I am willing to rotate each image in a form (certain angle of degree).
So i need code for rotating drawable over canvas.
The thing is that rotation of any drawable must not reflect to another drawable over Canvas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotating Image on A canvas in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712652/rotating-image-on-a-canvas-in-android)

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
yourCanvas.rotate(90);
```

[public void rotate (float degrees) on Android.Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#rotate%28float%29)