# I want to rotate around its center. before writing to a text on drawable

Tags: android

I have a drawable.  I want to rotate around its center before writing to a text on drawable

```
drawable= this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image);

final int IMAGE_WIDTH = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
final int IMAGE_HEIGHT = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(IMAGE_WIDTH, 
                                      IMAGE_HEIGHT, 
                                      Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas imageCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 

Paint imagePaint = new Paint();
imagePaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
imagePaint.setTextSize(16f);

drawable.draw(imageCanvas);

imageCanvas.drawText("", 
                     IMAGE_WIDTH / 2, 
                     (IMAGE_HEIGHT - imagePaint.ascent()) / 2, 
                     imagePaint);                   

LayerDrawable finalImage = new LayerDrawable(
     new Drawable[]{drawable, new BitmapDrawable(bitmap)});
```

Comment: You want to rotate what?

Comment: an image from resources drawable

Comment: Perhaps you can do like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712652/rotating-image-on-a-canvas-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
Bitmap  bmpOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.image);                      
                    final int IMAGE_WIDTH = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
                    final int IMAGE_HEIGHT = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();                                         
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.postRotate(rotate);
                    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0,width, height, matrix, true);
                    Canvas imageCanvas = new Canvas(resizedBitmap); 
                    BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);

                    Paint imagePaint = new Paint();
                    imagePaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
                    imagePaint.setTextSize(14f);

                    bmd.draw(imageCanvas);

                    imageCanvas.drawText("Text", 
                                             IMAGE_WIDTH / 2, 
                                             (IMAGE_HEIGHT - imagePaint.ascent()) / 2, 
                                             imagePaint);                   

                    LayerDrawable finalImage = new LayerDrawable(
                         new Drawable[]{bmd, new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap)});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html) to do all your rotation games and then set it to your [canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#setMatrix%28android.graphics.Matrix%29).

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is View Animation.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Tween