# Android : canvas.drawBitmap() method not working properly

Tags: android, canvas, pie-chart

I already post two question related this (plz refer this
[custom piechart 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28343600/customize-pie-chart-in-quarter-shape-at-the-bottom-left-of-the-screen-in-android)  and this [custom pie chart 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404656/pie-chart-in-android-without-third-party-in-android)) but not getting answer ,finally i develop my own but getting stuck at some point .

I need to create lines between drawn area as you can see in image .for inner circle i used `canvas.drawArc()` .for outer circle i used `canvas.drawCircle()` and for middle lines i used `canvas.drawBitmap()` method with differ angle .here inner and outer circle drawn properly but for middle arc ,only first two bitmap/arcs are  drawn properly but remaining two are not in their exact position .

I used same code for drawing all bitmap/arcs but not getting exact output .I am getting stuck what is the exact problem.need help ,thanks in advance .

you can see my output

here.. [image: screenshot]

Hear is my **onCreate()** , in which i generate and set view .

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);     
        matrix = new Matrix();  
        MyView myview = new MyView(this);
        lv1.addView(myview);
    }
```

this is my **customview class** that i want to generate.

```
    public class MyView extends View {

    private Paint p ,paint,paint_text;
    private int startX;
    private int startY;
    private int radius;
    private ArrayList<Integer> colors;
    private ArrayList<Float> values;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Context mContext;
    RectF rectF , rectF2 ;
    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        p = new Paint();
        p.setAntiAlias(true);

        colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        values = new ArrayList<Float>();

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
        width1 = display.getWidth();
        height1 = display.getHeight();      

        startX = 0 ;
        startY = 0;
        radius = (int) (width1/2);             

        colors.add(Color.RED);
        colors.add(Color.BLUE);
        colors.add(Color.YELLOW);
        colors.add(Color.GREEN);            
        values.add(8f);
        values.add(2f); 
        values.add(4f);         
        values.add(2f);         
    }
```

This is my **onDraw()** method .

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);           
        float _angle1 = 0 ,_angle2  = 0 ,_angle3 = 0 , _angle4 =0;      

        Bitmap myBitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.saperate_line);           
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);

        float offset = 0;       
        float angle = (float) 5.60 ;            
        matrix.reset();
        canvas.translate(0,canvas.getHeight()); //reset where 0,0 is located
        canvas.scale(1,-1); // for scaling 

        rectF = new RectF();
        rectF.set(-(getStartX() + getRadius()), -(getStartY() + getRadius()), getStartX() + getRadius(),getStartY() + getRadius());

       //for creating outer circle using canvas.drawCircle-----------
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);        
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);            
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);         
        canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, (float) (width1/(1.4)), paint); 

       //for creating inner circle using canvas.drawArc-----------
        for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
             p.setColor(colors.get(i));

            if (i == 0) {                   
             canvas.drawArc(rectF, offset, values.get(i) * angle, true, p);   
             _angle1 = ((offset+(values.get(i) * angle)))/2;                    
             matrix.postRotate(_angle1);    
             canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap1, matrix, null);          

            } 

           if(i == 1){              
              canvas.drawArc(rectF, offset, values.get(i) * angle, true, p);                
              _angle2 = ((offset + (values.get(i) * angle)))/2;
              matrix.postRotate(_angle2);
               canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap1, matrix, null);
             }  

           if(i == 2){
            canvas.drawArc(rectF, offset, values.get(i) * angle, true, p);          
            _angle3 = ((offset + (values.get(i) * angle)))/2;

            // _angle3 = (offset + angle);                  
             matrix.postRotate(_angle3);
             canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap1, matrix, null);        
              } 

           if (i == 3){                                     
             canvas.drawArc(rectF, offset, values.get(i) * angle, true, p); 
             _angle4 = ((offset + (values.get(i) * angle)))/2;                
             matrix.postRotate(_angle4);                    
             canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap1, matrix, null);
                }                        

            offset += (values.get(i) * angle);
            Log.e("new offset :: ","****************************"+offset);

        }
       canvas.save();    

    }
```

Comment: 90 degrees / (8 + 2 + 4 + 2) = 5.625, not 5.60

Comment: this calculation is for calculating angle of  inner circle , not for the arc . is  this effect on arcs ? apart from this i tried 5.625 but no luck @samgak

Comment: **1** `for middle lines i used canvas.drawBitmap()` **WHY**? couldn't you use `canvas.drawLine()` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawLine%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)? **2** Instead of going crazy with reinventing the wheel, couldn't you use a free 3rd party library, such as [aChartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org/content/demo.html)?

Comment: I tried this but can not customize aChartEnfine at this level .about canvas.drawLine() ,it accept  (startX,startY, stopX, stopY,  paint) as a argument , how can i calculate this parameter run time ,that fit exactly half of my particular portion (like blue ,green etc..) of chart ? - @DerGolem

Comment: can't catch you clearly ,i didn't use radius/2 . I think you told me about _angle1 = ((offset+(values.get(i) * angle)))/2;  this is for calculating angle from the (point of starting arc + point of ending arc ) / 2 .that gives me exact angle of drawing bitmap .-@DerGolem

Comment: aChartEnging gives us overall data in 360' degree but i want all data in to 1/4 part of 360' , you can say all data in quarter pie chart ,not in to full pie chart. that is way i have to go with canvas.-@DerGolem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to every one.
finally i did it using replacing this stuff [Rotating Image on A canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712652/rotating-image-on-a-canvas-in-android)

```
 matrix.postRotate(_angle1);    
 canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap1, matrix, null);
```

with this

```
Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix();
matrix1.setRotate(_angle1, 0, 0);
canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap1, matrix1, null);
```

here ,first you should change the value like this ,

```
 float myAngle = 0;
 myAngle = ((90 * values.get(i)) / 16);
```