# How to give border to circle using paint

Tags: android, paint, android-progressbar, stroke

Hi i have implemented Progress bar and it is working fine, but my problem is i need to give a only border to circle using paint. I worked on that but it is taking all the area of circle, i need only border.

My paint code:

```
    mCirclePaint = new Paint();
    mCirclePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mCirclePaint.setDither(true);
    mCirclePaint.setColor(mCircleColor);
    mCirclePaint.setStrokeWidth(mCircleStrokeWidth);
    mCirclePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mCirclePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
    // mCirclePaint.setShadowLayer(4.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, Color.BLACK);
    mCirclePaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.SQUARE);
    canvas.drawPath(mCirclePath, mCirclePaint)
```

Comment: Have you try anything ?

Comment: @harshadpansuriya Yes tried with changing values in paint n all and i posted code also

Comment: show your progress bar shape xml or code. ?

Comment: Where you want to draw border? On progress or on bg?

Comment: @BasilMiller I want on bg

Comment: Ok. Wait for solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try this ,

```
paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);        
paint.setStrokeWidth(2);            
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);         
canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, (float) (width1/(1.4)), paint);
```

and refer this , might be help full to you .[Android : canvas.drawBitmap() method not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690202/android-canvas-drawbitmap-method-not-working-properly)

Comment: find width1 = display.getWidth(); there.

Comment: No :( it is not working. It is not showing bg grey circle with above code

Comment: use this and let me know if you stuck .https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2182

Comment: Can u look this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053719/how-to-set-the-border-line-to-semi-circle-progress-bar-edge

Comment: I implemented a border but i am struck in edges

Comment: can you pest some of your code portion that draw your edges as you mention in your second question ?

Comment: Ya sure c shall we chat in chat room

Answer (score 1):

This is my code for your solution. Just copy this class and try to understand what your were doing wrong. This view will draw progress bar in center of view.

```
    /**
     * Created by GIGAMOLE on 23.01.2016.
     */
    public class StrokeProgressBar extends View {

    private final static float BAR_STROKE = 10.0f;
    private final static float BAR_HEIGHT = 60.0f;
    private final static float BAR_PADDING = 100.0f;

    private final Paint mProgressPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG) {
        {
            setDither(true);
            setAntiAlias(true);
            setColor(Color.BLUE);
            setStyle(Style.FILL);
        }
    };

//    private final Paint mBgPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG) {
//        {
//            setDither(true);
//            setAntiAlias(true);
//            setColor(Color.GRAY);
//            setStyle(Style.FILL);
//        }
//    };

    private final Paint mBgStrokePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG) {
        {
            setDither(true);
            setAntiAlias(true);
            setColor(Color.BLUE);
            setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            setStrokeWidth(BAR_STROKE);
            setStrokeCap(Cap.SQUARE);
        }
    };

    public StrokeProgressBar(final Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public StrokeProgressBar(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public StrokeProgressBar(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        // Draw always
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        final float height = canvas.getClipBounds().height();
        final float width = canvas.getClipBounds().width();

        // Background rect
        final Rect bgRect = new Rect(
                (int) BAR_PADDING,
                (int) (height / 2.0f - BAR_HEIGHT / 2.0f),
                (int) (width - BAR_PADDING),
                (int) (height / 2.0f + BAR_HEIGHT / 2.0f)
        );
        // Progress bar rect
        final Rect progressRect = new Rect(
                (int) BAR_PADDING,
                (int) (height / 2.0f - BAR_HEIGHT / 2.0f),
                (int) ((width - BAR_PADDING) * 0.7f), // 0.7f is the fraction of progress == 70%
                (int) (height / 2.0f + BAR_HEIGHT / 2.0f)
        );

        // At first draw stroke
        canvas.drawRect(
                bgRect,
                mBgStrokePaint
        );
//        // At second draw bg
//        canvas.drawRect(
//                bgRect,
//                mBgPaint
//        );
        // At third draw progress
        canvas.drawRect(
                progressRect,
                mProgressPaint
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Your suggestion I will check the code and let you know:)