# Rotate a text in a bitmap using canvas

Tags: android, image, text, rotation, android-canvas

The bitmap only contain the text so the width and the height of the bitmap are  determined by text's width and height and some math. now when i rotate the text using

```
canvas.rotate(tilt - 180, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2);
//the seek bar has a range of 0 to 360 so in order to get the right tilt i need to use (tilt - 180) instead of (tilt)
```

this is what happen

[image]

well obviously center of the rotation is wrong. I'v tried to use canvas.translate and the result have got better but they are yet not correct:

```
    float actualTilt = Math.abs(tilt - 180);
    actualTilt = (actualTilt >= 90 && actualTilt != 180) ? 90 - actualTilt % 90 : actualTilt;
    if (actualTilt == 180) actualTilt = 0;
    // by above statements i make sure actualTilt is less than 90 and it's values are 0,1,...89,90,89,88,...0
    float v = actualTilt / 90;
    canvas.translate((-(textWidth / 2) * v), (textHeight / 2) * v);
    //i don't understand the above statement either but this is the result
```

[image]

if texts get longer the result get even worst

Comment: if i need to use a completely different method tell me please..

Answer (score 0):

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712652/rotating-image-on-a-canvas-in-android) the following codeto rotate a bitmap in a canvas:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate(angle, imageCenterX, imageCenterY);
yourCanvas.drawBitmap(yourBitmap, matrix, null);
```

Have you tried this out?

Comment: yes i did try matrix not that code exactly but it didn't work [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712652/rotating-image-on-a-canvas-in-android) 
 the code you've suggested also doesn't work

Comment: How does it looks like?

Comment: http://imgur.com/o0dNiiL
ignoring the weird effect the text still goes out of bound @KimKulling

Comment: Which center of rotation have you used? It does not look correctly for me in the moment.Have you tried to use a local rotation?

Comment: center of the text bitmap. thanks for your time but I've solved the issue by tilting the whole bitmap as i was unable to tilt the text only... it has resulted in another issue but it would be off topic to talk about. i'll try to post my own answer thanks again...