# How can I make a copy of an image on disk as it appears in the ImageView?

Tags: android

I'm loading an image in to a number of different ImageViews, each with different ScaleTypes. Additionally, some images can be rotated using a Glide transformation before being displayed.

I'd like to be able to make a copy of the original image and crop, rotate, resize it in the same way as it is displayed in the ImageViews.

At the moment I'm grabbing a Bitmap from the ImageView itself but the quality is obviously much lower than the original source image.

Is there a way that I could use the properties of this bitmap and apply them to the original image?

Answer (score 0):

For **saving** file you can do this

```
    FileOutputStream out = null;
try {
    out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
    // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the original answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/save-bitmap-to-location)

For your **rotating**, **cropping**, **resizing** image, you can use **canvas** and **matrix** Android APIs.
Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712652/rotating-image-on-a-canvas-in-android)

And here is [Canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) API

Comment: Yes but how would I rotate, crop and resize it to match how it is displayed in the imageview?

Comment: if you had posted some code then we could look into it but i have given a link which is also easy to do just create a class and extend from View and then in onDraw() you are suppose to use those methods posted in answer linked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing that too often in your app, then maybe you are using the wrong library. Please refer this post for more info. https://medium.com/@multidots/glide-vs-picasso-930eed42b81d