# Android Google Maps auto-rotate

Tags: android, google-maps, android-sensors, autorotate, compass

I am trying to implement a map app with auto-rotate function (when pressing on corresponding button) based on compass heading. I used the answer of this question and adapt it to my project:
[android maps auto-rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320015/android-maps-auto-rotate)

Since my device does not support Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR, I modified the code using Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION (deprecated). Currently, it works well. The only problem is that the rotation effect of the map has no continuity. The animation runs shakingly. I checked some other apps and I liked their rotation effect. Their map smoothly rotates.

In order to eliminate this problem, can you advise an improvement?

My implementation is this:

```
float mDeclination;
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
Sensor sensor;
boolean isCompassOn = false;

private GoogleMap map; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);

}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    GeomagneticField field = new GeomagneticField(
            (float)location.getLatitude(),
            (float)location.getLongitude(),
            (float)location.getAltitude(),
            System.currentTimeMillis()
    );

    mDeclination = field.getDeclination();
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION && isCompassOn) {
        updateCamera(event.values[0] + mDeclination);
    }
}

private void updateCamera(float bearing) {
    CameraPosition oldPos = map.getCameraPosition();
    CameraPosition pos = CameraPosition.builder(oldPos).bearing(bearing).build();
    GoogleMap.CancelableCallback callback = new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }
    };
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(pos), 24, callback);
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
```

Comment: This might be able to help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320015/android-maps-auto-rotate

Comment: I referred same link above.