# Android - Display Radar on GoogleMap

Tags: android, google-maps

I have created an android app. In that I am generating randomly 10 `Latitude` and 10 `Logitude`. (and 10 names given to each marker) and displaying it on `GoogleMap`

But, now I want to put a radar on the map which gives a direction.. and accordingly I want to show which person is in which direction..

Please check the image, I want to show something like this.

[image]

Any Help??

Thank You...

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: It seems like he tried : "I have created an android app. In that I am generating randomly 10 Latitude and 10 Logitude. (and 10 names given to each marker) and displaying it on GoogleMap" something.. so it would be ok if someone could guide him to some tutorials

Comment: @dilix:: I don't know how to implement radar.. so I was asking for the tutorials or any sample program to implement radar.. and how could u help if I share my existing code with you. because it's just randomly generating latitude, longitude and names and printing it on the map.. That code will not help anyone to solve the problem I asked above..

Comment: @Hitman:: Thank u.. need serious help.. It's a live project and I want to run this as soon as possible..

Comment: This image looks very nice, but if you haven't tried to code it yourself, nobody can really help you. This is a very specific requirement (which you didn't describe well enough) and you need to at least know what components to use to: 1) find position and direction of the user, 2) draw arcs, circles, 3) set up backend to save and share users' positions. If you have specific problems with implementation of any of these, that would have been a better question for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so for start you can try detect the direction. To do that look over this question&answer and try to do this: [Calculate compass bearing / heading to location in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308262/calculate-compass-bearing-heading-to-location-in-android) . In this way you can know where the user is looking at. After that maybe you could have an png image that you could draw over the map headed to the direction calculated like in the link I just posted.

Comment: Probably it will solve my problem.. :0 will try to figure it out.. will need you if i stuck anywhere.. be in touch.. thank you.. :)

Comment: ok, if i know how i will help you