# Easiest way convert UTM ZONE to lat long

Tags: gis, latitude-longitude, utm

I'm looking for the easiest way convert utm  to lat / long
If the server-side code is better.

for example utm
EASTING  NORTHING
521937.7447 3955151.601

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to convert UTM coordinates (`easting` and `northing`) to latitude and longitude you need the zone `number` and zone `letter` as well.
Without these your easting / northing values could be in any of the **60 zones** defined by UTM.
As for libraries, there are packages for [Python](https://pypi.org/project/utm/), [Javascript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utm) and probably others.
Sample for JS:

```
utm.toLatLon(easting, northing, zoneNum, zoneLetter)
//returns { latitude, longitude }

utm.fromLatLon(latitude, longitude)
//returns { easting, northing, zoneNum, zoneLetter }
```

Comment: For Java you can use geotools or just do the math directly, more details in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176137/java-convert-lat-lon-to-utm).

Answer (score 2):

You can use ST_Transform in Postgis if you have access to this

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html

Example:

```
ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(the_geom, 27700), 4326)))
```