# How to download maven dependency as *.jar file?

Tags: java, xml, maven, geotools

I attempt to implement the example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176137/java-convert-lat-lon-to-utm), but upon the Maven dependencies installation I can't find jar file amongst downloaded dependencies.

My `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- This is often your domain name (reversed.)  -->
    <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
    <!-- The name of this project (actually, the name of the artifact, which is the thing that this project produces. A jar in this case.) -->
    <artifactId>javaparser-maven-sample</artifactId>
    <!-- The version of this project. SNAPSHOT means "we're still working on it" -->
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <!-- Tell Maven we want to use Java 8 -->
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <!-- Tell Maven to treat all source files as UTF-8 -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <geotools.version>2.5.7</geotools.version>
    </properties>
   <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net repository</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>osgeo</id>
        <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
        <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository> <!--Add the snapshot repository here-->
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>opengeo</id>
        <name>OpenGeo Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.opengeo.org</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Here are all your dependencies. Currently only one. These are automatically downloaded from https://mvnrepository.com/ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javaparser</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaparser-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.15.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mil.nga.geopackage/geopackage -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mil.nga.geopackage</groupId>
            <artifactId>geopackage</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools/gt-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-api</artifactId>
            <version>20.5</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools/gt-geometry -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-geometry</artifactId>
        <version>2.5-M2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools/gt-referencing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-referencing</artifactId>
        <version>17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.locationtech.jts.io/jts-io-common -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.locationtech.jts.io</groupId>
        <artifactId>jts-io-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.opengis/geoapi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opengis</groupId>
        <artifactId>geoapi</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools/gt-jts-wrapper -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
    <artifactId>gt-jts-wrapper</artifactId>
    <version>17.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
            <version>17.0</version>
        </dependency>

    
    
    </dependencies>

    <!-- This blob of configuration tells Maven to make the jar executable. You can run it with:
    mvn clean package
    java -jar target/javaparser-maven-sample-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar
    -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.abc.conversion.LogicPositivizer</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am able to download all the jars except geotools related jars. When I clean and run the project, in the `.m2` folder I am not able to see the geotool related jars. Even in the maven repository I am not able to download the jar file.

[Maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools/gt-api/20.5)

Is there any alternative way to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repository run by Boundless has been replaced by one hosted by OSGeo.  The OSGeo webdav repo was merged into the new OSGeo repo.  Details are here (https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/maven.html)

Replace this block

```
<repository>
    <id>osgeo</id>
    <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
    <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
</repository>
<repository> <!--Add the snapshot repository here-->
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
    <id>opengeo</id>
    <name>OpenGeo Maven Repository</name>
    <url>http://repo.opengeo.org</url>
</repository>
```

with

```
  <repository>
    <id>osgeo</id>
    <name>OSGeo Release Repository</name>
    <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/</url>
    <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
  </repository>
  <repository>
    <id>osgeo-snapshot</id>
    <name>OSGeo Snapshot Repository</name>
    <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/snapshot/</url>
    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
  </repository>
```

Comment: Isn't that the same thing I've said before?

Comment: No.  The Boundless repo you suggested has been decommissioned.  At this point, GeoTools is available on the OSGeo repo listed above and described in the GeoTools quickstart.

Answer (score 0):

If you paste the `Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository` URL in your web browser and hit enter it will return `404 Not Found` error. This happens when Maven attempts to connect to that resource to fetch dependency for you but it's no longer available. However, if you pay close attention to `Maven Repo` link, there is a note:

> Note: this artefact is located at Boundless repository (https://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main/)

Try to replace `http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/` with a given in the note URL and run `mvn clean install`

Please let me know if that worked for you.

Comment: Where do I need to replace `http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/`

Comment: <repository>
        <id>osgeo</id>
        <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
        *<url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>*
    </repository>

url in <url> tag

Comment: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.abc:javaparser-maven-sample:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.geotools:gt-api:jar:20.5: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.geotools:gt-api:jar:20.5: Could not transfer artifact org.geotools:gt-api:pom:20.5 from/to osgeo (https://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main/): repo.boundlessgeo.com: Unknown host repo.boundlessgeo.com